# Get total RowCount for TableLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I have a TableLayout in which I add the Table Column titles in my Layout XML file, and add other rows dynamically through the code(based on a condition). So there are cases when no rows are added to the table.
I need to check if no rows exist for the table. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Through this code you can get the total `rowCount` for `TableLayout`

```
TableLayoutName.getChildCount();
```

This method return the total number of rows in integer value.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using getChildCount() ? You can even make use of getChildAt(int value) .

Comment: This works! To check for empty Table, I just check for tableLayout.getChildCount() less than or equal to the number of rows I initially add in my layout XML. And it works.. :)